# multi-edge bevel on half-edge structure

Tags: algorithm, graph, 3d, computational-geometry, mesh

I am looking for a sample implementation, or pseudo code, of multi-edge bevel on a half-edge datastructure. Single edge bevel is easy - but multiple-edges at once... I tried now for several hours without success. I'm only struggling with the topological changes, pushing the vertices propperly doesn't look that difficult.
Basically, I'm looking for an algorithm on how to get from the left mesh to the right mesh on a half-edge data structure:
[image: topology change]
[image]

Can anyone point me to a paper, a book or a sample implementation of multi-edge bevel?

Answer (score 2):

We can split the operation into two conceptual steps. First, double the red edges. Second, explode the vertices incident to at least one red edge.

The first step can be accomplished one edge at a time. Given a red edge e, create another edge e'. For one half edge of e, insert one half edge of e' as the next half-edge with the same head in clockwise order. For the other half edge of e, insert the other half edge of e' as the next half edge with the same head in counterclockwise order.

The second step can be accomplished one vertex at a time. Given a vertex v incident to at least one red edge, group the half edges with head v as follows. Break that circular list (1) between every adjacent pair of red half edges that arose from the same original edge (2) between every adjacent pair of white edges (adjacent means that the two half edges are next/previous in clockwise/counterclockwise order). For each break, create a new edge. Splice everything together. (This involves operating on the ends of the broken pieces and the new edges. I think that a detailed description at the level of detail in this answer would be unhelpful.)

Comment: Hello and thank you. So far it doesn't make so much sense to me however. I agree a first step is to insert duplicate edges. What does not make sense to me for example is "For the other half edge of e, insert the other half edge of e' as the next half edge with the same head in counterclockwise order." It makes sense to me that the "inner" halfedges of e and e' point to each other, creating a circular ahlfedge pair - but why the "outer" ones? also, the "splice everything together" is what I was struggling with mainly.

Comment: Perhaps not explained very clearly this answer is solid. Essentially: normally when you chamfer a vertex (what David called explode) a new edge is created between every spoke edge. While in this case, after adding the initial new red edges, you only want to create an edge between two red and two white spoke edges, not between a red and a white spoke edge. In practice, first create the delete vertex function, a connect vertices function (creates edge between 2 verts) which  can be used to create a chamfer vertex function. The latter should skip creating an edge between red and white spokes.